# CSS image masking, img with % height

Tags: css, calc

Here's a challenge, basically I've got a CMS with images that have transparency on the sides and I'm trying to mask them I've managed to get the side's masked but the bottom doesn't seem to work. Here's a link to the JS fiddle file: https://jsfiddle.net/zqvktews/3/

Cropping the images is not an option, I've got a 400+ of them...

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
 <img class="inside" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/56f9678288dad33d7bb08de2/58b985d6b807bda0073d7511_255_Fortuna_v.png" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test{
 width: 20%;
 background: red;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.inside{
 width: calc(100% + 20px);
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Can't you fix the height of the container (class test) ? Or you could crop with a PHP (or any other language) script.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because these are meant to resize with percentages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change things slightly:

- Remove the [extra inline gap underneath the image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/2930477) with `display: block`
- Pad the width by 10px with the calc. Moving the image can now be done in increments of 5px
- Stick the image to the bottom, cutting the image with `bottom: -5px`
- Pull the image back up with a negative 10px margin
- Pull the image left with -5px margin

Like this:

```
.inside{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  margin: -10px 0 0 -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

Gives us:

[image: Example screenshot]

#### Full example

Note: For this example I have re-hosted the images so the link wont break. They are now jpgs with a white gap around the image, instead of transparent.

```css
.test {
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inside {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  margin: -10px 0 0 -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img class="inside" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rVY.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="test">
  <img class="inside" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rVY.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="test">
  <img class="inside" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rVY.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution, although a maybe ugly one:

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
 <div class="inner">
  <img class="inside" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/56f9678288dad33d7bb08de2/58b985d6b807bda0073d7511_255_Fortuna_v.png" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
 width: 20%;
 background: red;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.inner{
 background-image: url("http://uploads.webflow.com/56f9678288dad33d7bb08de2/58b985d6b807bda0073d7511_255_Fortuna_v.png");
 display: block;
 background-size: calc(100% + 20px);
 background-position: -10px -10px; 
}

.inside{
   width:100%;
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

Short form of what I did here:

I wrapped the original image by an additional container. Instead of making the image 20px larger, I made it invisible (though keeping its reserved space). The inner container now gets the same image as a background which is streched and moved according to your requirement.

The possible problems here: Your image is not an image anymore, although you could achieve the same with an image showing just a transparent pixel (if you really want to keep the alt-tag). It's not strict perfect html, but it would render correctly on screen and in html text readers.